# I need a SQL query for SELECT usename, usesuper, usecreatedb FROM pg_catalog.pg_user ORDER BY role_name desc;

Tags: postgresql

I want to see all.SELECT usename, usesuper, usecreatedb
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
ORDER BY role_name desc;SELECT usename, usesuper, usecreatedb
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
ORDER BY role_name desc;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you this request to see all the users of your database:

```
postgres-# \du
```

If you want more information from your users you can use:

```
postgres-# \du+
```

I advise you this request if you have more difficulties

```sql
SELECT usename AS role_name,
 CASE
  WHEN usesuper AND usecreatedb THEN
    CAST('superuser, create database' AS pg_catalog.text)

  WHEN usesuper THEN
    CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)

  WHEN usecreatedb THEN
    CAST('create database' AS pg_catalog.text)

  ELSE
    CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
 END role_attributes
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
ORDER BY role_name desc;
```

I advise you to show this doc:
[https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-list-all-users-in-postgresql/#:~:text=Using%20psql%20command,-Log%20into%20PostgreSQL&text=Enter%20password%20to%20log%20into%20PostgreSQL.&text=Enter%20%5Cdu%20command%20to%20list%20all%20users%20in%20PostrgeSQL.&text=You%20will%20see%20the%20list,user%2C%20enter%20%5Cdu%2B%20command](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-list-all-users-in-postgresql/#:%7E:text=Using%20psql%20command,-Log%20into%20PostgreSQL&text=Enter%20password%20to%20log%20into%20PostgreSQL.&text=Enter%20%5Cdu%20command%20to%20list%20all%20users%20in%20PostrgeSQL.&text=You%20will%20see%20the%20list,user%2C%20enter%20%5Cdu%2B%20command).

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query to get the list of users and roles in your PostgreSQL database:

```
SELECT usename, usesuper, usecreatedb 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
ORDER BY role_name desc;
```